# PHP SQL / multible select request / slow

Tags: php, pdo

I have 2 requests on a SQL database. It takes really long to load the whole script / page. Is there a better (faster) way? My code looks like this

```
    $abfrage = "SELECT * FROM table_a WHERE state = '0' ORDER BY EDIT DESC";
        $stmt = $pdo->query($abfrage);

        foreach($stmt as $data) { ?>

$usern = $data['user_name'];
$stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM tabl_b WHERE user_name = '$usern' ORDER BY follower DESC Limit 1");
$stmt->execute();
$pl = $stmt->fetch();

<?php echo $data['ID'];?>
        <?php echo $data['ID'];?>

        <?php if ($data['company'] == '') { ?>
        <a href="https://open.spotify.com/user/<?php echo $data['user_name'];?>" target="_blank"><?php if ($data['state'] == '3') { echo "<span style=\"color:#0000FF\";>".$data['user_name']."</span>"; } else { echo $data['user_name'];}?></a>
        <?php } else {?>

        <a href="https://open.spotify.com/user/<?php echo $data['user_name'];?>" target="_blank"><?php if ($data['state'] == '3') { echo "<span style=\"color:#0000FF\";>".$data['company']."</span>"; } else { echo $data['company'];}?></a>

        <?php } ?>

        <?php echo $data['PL_read'];?>
        <?php echo $data['PL_total'];?>
        <?php echo $data['country'];?>
        <?php echo $data['EDIT'];?>
    <?php echo $pl['follower'];?>
        <?php } ?>
```

I have a table around th echo data. I would be great if someone can give me a tip.

Comment: is there too many object into your table?, i'm not really into php, but i had this problem in java and the only way to speed this kind of thing is paginating them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First if tables have relation I suggest you to take the data in a single call with join.

```
SELECT * FROM table_a a
LEFT JOIN tabl_b b ON a.user_name = b.user_name
WHERE a.state = '0'
```

Second for speeding up the things you can put INDEX on the two fields that you are using in the WHERE clause - state, user_name

```
ALTER TABLE `table_a` ADD INDEX `state` (`state`)
ALTER TABLE `tabl_b` ADD INDEX `user_name` (`user_name`)
```

Comment: Wow - it´s much faster. What happens, when i add INDEX to the table?

Comment: Yes it should, if there is no INDEX the search is performed against the whole table data. When you have INDEX the search is made only in the necessary fields http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-indexes.html

Answer (score 0):

1. When it comes for loading time then we should only fetch those column from table which are required, So in first query we can fetch user_name, ID, company, PL_read, PL_total, country, EDIT
2. Since the query which are running inside loop will also take time, so to avoid this use below code

   ```
       $dataArray = array();
       $userName = NULL;
       $abfrage = "SELECT ID, user_name, company, PL_read, PL_total, country, EDIT FROM table_a WHERE state = '0' ORDER BY EDIT DESC";
       $stmt = $pdo->query($abfrage);

       foreach($stmt as $data) {
           //creating a string
           if (is_null($userName))
           {
               $userName = "'" . $data['user_name'] . "'";
           }
           else
           {
               $userName .= ",'" . $data['user_name'] . "'";
           }
           $dataArray[$userName] = $data;
       }

       $stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT follower, user_name FROM tabl_b WHERE      user_name IN ($userName) ORDER BY follower");

       foreach($stmt as $data) { 
           if(isset($dataArray[$userName]))
           {
               $dataArray[$userName]['follower'] = $data['follower'];
           }
           else
           {
               $dataArray[$userName]['follower'] = 'N/A';
           }
       }

       foreach($dataArray as $data) { 
               echo $data['ID'];?>
               <?php echo $data['ID'];?>

               <?php if ($data['company'] == '') { ?>
                   <a href="https://open.spotify.com/user/<?php echo $data['user_name'];?>" target="_blank"><?php if ($data['state'] == '3') { echo "<span style=\"color:#0000FF\";>".$data['user_name']."</span>"; } else { echo $data['user_name'];}?></a>
               <?php } else {?>
                   <a href="https://open.spotify.com/user/<?php echo $data['user_name'];?>" target="_blank"><?php if ($data['state'] == '3') { echo "<span style=\"color:#0000FF\";>".$data['company']."</span>"; } else { echo $data['company'];}?></a>

               <?php } ?>

               <?php echo $data['PL_read'];?>
               <?php echo $data['PL_total'];?>
               <?php echo $data['country'];?>
               <?php echo $data['EDIT'];?>
               <?php echo $pl['follower'];?>
    <?php } ?>
   ```